# Represent a Git merge in former commits (fake a merge)

Tags: git

I have two branches, *master* and *upstream*. Once in a while, *upstream* is imported/merged into master.

How can I properly tie these back together?

It's a lot easier to explain with a diagram:

I have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
\     |
 |    /
 \   /
  X--Y--Z
```

It should have been (and I want):

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
\     |       /
 |    /   ___/
 \   /   /
  X--Y--Z
```

I *know* there's a way to do this (with the plumbing commands).

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

For those with the same problem down the road, here's what I did. Refer to the diagrams here, not in the original post (I added a few more commits for clarity).

First, grab the timestamps for that commit from the log. If we don't use these timestamps later on, our new merge will have a more recent timestamp than commits G..K! So, do `git log --format=fuller` to see your log with the CommitDate and AuthorDate for each commit. In the example scenario, the timestamps we're looking for are from the commit `E`. Then:

Before:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K         master
\     |
 |    /
 \   /
  X--Y--Z                               upstream
```

Commands:

```
git branch temp
git reset --hard E
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="..." GIT_COMMIT_DATE="..." git merge Z
git cherry-pick G..K
```

After:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J--K         master
\     |       /
 |    /   ___/
 \   /   /
  X--Y--Z                               upstream
```

Comment: What does `git branch temp` do?

Comment: Guess: make sure Git doesn't prune the no-longer-reacheable commits G..K.