# Is it possible to make an existing git commit appear as a merge?

Tags: git, merge

I have a git tree:

```
A--B---------E'--F--G (master)
    \       
     C--D--E
```

`E'` is a squashed version of `C--D--E` that was not committed via merge.  Ideally it would have been committed as a no-fast-forward merge to look like:

```
A--B---------E'--F--G (master)
    \       /
     C--D--E
```

Is there any way to create the `E` to `E'` link without rebasing later commits (and changing their commit hashes)? (Primarily I just want the graph   to look more accurate.)

(I've read [Represent a Git merge in former commits (fake a merge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966910/represent-a-git-merge-in-former-commits-fake-a-merge), which is a very similar question, but it doesn't do what I want.)

Comment: Merge `E` and `E'` and a merge commit will be created. Merge the merge commit to `master`. Not perfect but no rebase and `C--D--E` is included in `master`'s history.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible to do that without affecting F and G commits. If you alter the commit's parents, the commit changes, so if E' is changed, then F must also be changed because it's parent is different.

Answer (score 2):

After reading [Git Tools - Replace](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace), I find it possible.

```
git checkout B
git merge E --no-ff
#let's say the created merge commit is O
git replace E' O
```

Or done by:

```
git replace --graft E' B E
```

`git replace` creates a ref as `.git/refs/replace/E'`. It can be pushed to another repository via `git push <remote> refs/replace/E'`, and it should be if you expect the replacement to work in other repositories.

If you don't need it any longer, `git replace -d E'` will remove the replacement. `git push <remote> :refs/replace/E` will remove it in the remote repository.

Now `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master` or `gitk master` shows the graph you expect. So far as I know, the only shortcoming is that now `git show E'` or `git log -1 E' -p` gives no patch but only the data of the merge commit. According to the manual, there are some known bugs, so it's a bit risky to use this feature.